# How to enable Horizontal Scrolling For chart.js in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, chart.js, chart.js2

I am using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html) version 2.7.2 in my ionic app for displaying a bar graph.

However, I am not able to get the chart to be scrollable along x-axis when there is more data. No matter how much data I add it fits into screen width. I want to maintain the width of each bar, display only 5 bars at a time and make the chart scrollable if there are more than 5 bars.

This is what I have :

[image: Current UI]

This is how I need it:

[image].

As you can see if there is more than 5 data, it should only display maximum 5 bars on a screen, and rest should be scrollable along x axis.

I am posting relevant parts of my code below:

HTML:

```
<ion-content scroll="false" text-center>
  <ion-grid>
   <ion-row class="graph-section">

    <canvas height="250%" #barCanvas></canvas>

   </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

CSS:

```
.graph-section{
        display:block;
       height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      }

      ion-grid {
        height: 100%;
      }
```

.ts File:

```
barChart: any;

 ionViewDidLoad() 
    {

        this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, 
            {

                chart:{'xAxisName' : "Quarter"},
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["5d", "2d", "1d ", "2h", "5min"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '',
                    data: [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',

                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',
                        'rgba(165, 217, 238)',

                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options:  {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{ 
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }

        });

  }
```

Comment: Hello
Do you find the way for this?
I also have the same requirement.

Any help will be great for me.